# Отображение в окне переменной boolean

Tags: java, массивы, swing

Программа записывает данные о работниках. 
Меня интересует переменная `Gender` Я хочу использовать именно `boolean` для этой переменной.
Так я обозначаю женский/мужской пол:

```
 public void setGender(boolean gender) {
            this.gender = gender;
            if(gender == true){
                System.out.println("Male");
            }else{
                System.out.println("Female");
            }
          }
```

Далее у меня в другом классе имеется `multidimensial array`, которая забирает данные с помощью `String`

```
String[][] records = {{"123456U", "Maria", "Larionova", "male", "Administration", "50", "1"},
               {"578943I", "Lora", "Tamm", "female", "female", "100", "2"},
               {"124783H", "Victor", "Rink", "male", "Transport", "150", "1"}      
    };

    public EmployeeMenu() {
        super("Personnel Application");
        for (int i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
            list.add(new Employee(records[i][0], records[i][1], records[i][2], 
                    Boolean.parseBoolean(records[i][3]), records[i][4], Integer.parseInt(records[i][5]), Integer.parseInt(records[i][6])));
        }
```

И естественно, когда я отображаю дынные в окне, на месте `gender` у меня написано `false/true` вместо `male/female`, хотя необходимо именно `male/female`!

Вызываю этот метод с помощью Swing компонентов:

```
genderLabel = new JLabel("Gender: "); 
    genderTextField = new JTextField(10); 
    genderTextField.setEditable(false);
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Вы наверное перепутали `toString()` и `System.out.println()`

Comment: Покажите код, где вы отображаете данные в окне.

Comment: @Leonid Lunin, возможно вы правы. у меня есть только один отдельный метод toString, который создан, чтобы отобразить данные. `public String toString() {
  return "PPS Number: " + pps + "\nLast Name: " + surname + "\nFirst Name: " + name + "\nGender: " + gender + "\nDepartment: " + dep + "\nSalary: " + salary + "\nFulltime: " + fulltime;
 }`

Comment: @Alex, пожалуйста: `genderLabel = new JLabel("Gender: ");
  genderTextField = new JTextField(10);
  genderTextField.setEditable(false);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public String getGender() {
            return gender?"Male":"Female"; 
          }
```

---

```
public String toString() {
    return "PPS Number: " + pps +
        "\nLast Name: " + surname +
        "\nFirst Name: " + name +
        "\nGender: " + getGender() +
        "\nDepartment: " + dep +
        "\nSalary: " + salary +
        "\nFulltime: " + fulltime;
}
```

Предположу, что за конечный вывод на экран отвечает содержимое элемента списка

```
list.add(new Employee(records[i][0], records[i][1], records[i][2], 
                    Boolean.parseBoolean(records[i][3]), records[i][4], Integer.parseInt(records[i][5]), Integer.parseInt(records[i][6])));
```

В таком случае ошибка в том, что вы через `Boolean.parseBoolean(records[i][3])` пытаетесь распарсить строку вида "male"/"female", тогда как этим методом надо парсить "false"/"true". Вообще у вас какая-то путаница типов. Непонятно, где оно `boolean`, и где превращается в строку. Попробуйте хранить его в `boolean`, работать с ним только как с `boolean`, и только при выводе на экран превращать его в строку методом `this.gender?"male":"female"`.
И совершенно точно не надо его хранить/задавать в виде "male"/"female" или (упаси боже) "true"/"false", превращая при чтении в булево: теряется весь смысл преобразования к булевому типу, получается, что оно задается/хранится как строка, потом на некоторое время превращается в булево, и при выводе потом снова превращается в строку.

Comment: Я добавила данный метод. Теперь у меня везде в окне отображается "Female", независимо от того, что также должно отображаться "Male"

Comment: Значит, `this.gender` у вас везде `false`. Покажите код, куда вы его добавили (класс целиком), и самое главное - как и откуда вы его вызываете, тогда смогу сказать, где ошибка. **UPD.** Увидел ваш комментарий к вопросу, исправил ответ.

Comment: спасибо, пока что все та же проблема. Я тоже обновила свой вопрос, и добавила кусочек, где я вызываю этот метод.

Comment: Очень сложно так разбираться, по фрагментам. Похоже на гадание на кофейной гуще. Сделаю еще одно предположение, добавлю в ответ сейчас.

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное за подробное объяснение! К вашим исправлениям я добавила: `String[][] records = {{"123456U", "Maria", "Larionova", "true", "Administration", "50", "1"}};`, чтобы значение в строке было не `Male`, а  `true`, и теперь все работает!